# Python join data lines together

Tags: python, python-2.7, dataset

Hello i have dataset a few thousand lines which is split in even and odd number lines and i can't find a way to join them together again in the same line. Reading the file and overwriting it is fine or making a new file.

I have found this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908317/python-even-numbered-lines-in-text-file) to print the seperate lines but can't get it to write it to file.

I would like it to look like this:

```
Time = 1 Temperature1 = 24.75 Temperature2 = 22.69 Temperature3 = 20.19 RPM = -60.00
Time = 2 Temperature1 = 24.75 Temperature2 = 22.75 Temperature3 = 20.19 RPM = -60.00
etc...
```

Example of dataset:

```
Time = 1 Temperature1 = 24.75 Temperature2 = 22.69 Temperature3 = 20.19
 RPM = -60.00
Time = 2 Temperature1 = 24.75 Temperature2 = 22.75 Temperature3 = 20.19
 RPM = -60.00
Time = 3 Temperature1 = 24.75 Temperature2 = 22.75 Temperature3 = 20.19
 RPM = -60.00
Time = 4 Temperature1 = 24.81 Temperature2 = 22.81 Temperature3 = 20.25
 RPM = -60.00
Time = 5 Temperature1 = 24.81 Temperature2 = 22.81 Temperature3 = 20.19
 RPM = -60.00
Time = 6 Temperature1 = 24.81 Temperature2 = 22.81 Temperature3 = 20.19
 RPM = -60.00
Time = 7 Temperature1 = 24.81 Temperature2 = 22.81 Temperature3 = 20.25
 RPM = -60.00
Time = 8 Temperature1 = 24.81 Temperature2 = 22.87 Temperature3 = 20.25
 RPM = -60.00
Time = 9 Temperature1 = 24.87 Temperature2 = 22.87 Temperature3 = 20.25
 RPM = -60.00
Time = 10 Temperature1 = 24.87 Temperature2 = 22.87 Temperature3 = 20.25
 RPM = -60.00
```

Comment: I recommend to use pandas dataframe. You can easily merge it and save to file.

Comment: Can you give me an example how? am kind of new to python and don't recognize the pandas dataframe, was looking through its documentation but cant see how to apply it to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `%` (modulus) to determine if the line is odd or even. If it's even, then join together the last line and the current line.

```
# Using your dataset as a string
data_split = data.split("\n")

for i in range(len(data_split)):
    if i % 2:
        lines = [data_split[i-1], data_split[i]]
        print " ".join(lines)
```

> Output:
>
> Time = 1 Temperature1 = 24.75 Temperature2 = 22.69 Temperature3 =
>   20.19  RPM = -60.00
>
> Time = 2 Temperature1 = 24.75 Temperature2 = 22.75 Temperature3 =
>   20.19  RPM = -60.00
>
> Time = 3 Temperature1 = 24.75 Temperature2 = 22.75 Temperature3 =
>   20.19  RPM = -60.00
>
> ...

Comment: Yeah i can see that it works as a string but when i import my file then the split command doesn't work with file type, then it won't print a thing out. And i am not sure how to write to a file from an IF statement. (Am new to python)

Comment: Managed to read the file into str variable with [code]data=myfile.read()

Comment: Got it to work with your code: 

`with open('LOGT.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()
    data_split = data.split("\n")

for i in range(len(data_split)):
    if i % 2:
        lines = [data_split[i-1], data_split[i]]
        joined = " ".join(lines)
        fh = open("LOGT1.txt","a")
        fh.write(joined)
        fh.write("\n")
        fh.close()`

Comment: Or you can use `readline()` instead and check if the line is odd or even. Glad you got something working though.